# How to download a pdf file in rails using dragonfly gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem regarding file download. I am using dragonfly gem to upload file. Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_for Term.new do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :term %>
    <%= f.file_field :term, required: true, multiple: true, name: 'term[term]' %>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-wrapper">
    <p>Bitrate: <span class="bitrate"></span></p>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
        0%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and here is my controller's action

```
def new_multiple
    @terms = Term.order('created_at DESC')
    @term = Term.new
  end
```

Now i don't know how i can download this uploaded file. Kindly guide me or suggest me something. What will be the action what will be the view and what will be the routes?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [*to_file* method](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/models/).

You can create an action in your controller to download the object, according to your form it should be approximately:

```
def download
  @terms = Terms.find(params[:id])
  send_file @term.term.to_file(@term.term_name)
end
```

Mind to create the appropriate route.